# Spotipy start playback returned 400 due to Non supported context uri

Tags: python, spotipy

I've been trying to use spotipy to search for a song using sp.search, and then using sp.start_playback I wanted to play it. However, for some reason, it gives an error saying the URI is non supported.

This is the code:

```
 def searchSong(said):
        devices = sp.devices()
        for device in devices['devices']:
            if device['is_active']:
                results = sp.search(q=said, type="track", limit=1, offset=0)
                
                track_id = results["tracks"]["items"][0]["uri"]

                print(track_id)
                sp.start_playback(device['id'], track_id)
```

and when run it returns:

```
spotify:track:72jFoOulGip53D9qZWMvi2
HTTP Error for PUT to https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=a1ab04dcf181639c4ee6b8dae30d2c1bb03f810b with Params: {} returned 400 due to Non supported context uri
Exception: http status: 400, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=a1ab04dcf181639c4ee6b8dae30d2c1bb03f810b:
 Non supported context uri, reason: None
```

I have no idea why this is, as the id should be correct?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.start_playback), the second parameter is for the context uri.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

# Set your Spotify app credentials (client ID and client secret)
client_id = '<your client ID>'
client_secret = '<your client Secret>'
redirect_uri = '<your redirect uri>' # my demo use http://localhost:3000/callback

# scopes for Remote control playback
SCOPEs = [ 'app-remote-control' ]

def searchSong(said):
    devices = sp.devices()
    for device in devices['devices']:
        if device['is_active']:
            results = sp.search(q=said, type="track", limit=1, offset=0)
            if (len(results["tracks"]["items"]) > 0):
                track_id = results["tracks"]["items"][0]["uri"]
                sp.start_playback(
                    device_id = device['id'],
                    uris = [track_id]
                )
                print('Play Song: ', results["tracks"]["items"][0]["name"])
            else:
                print("Can't find search keyword => {0}".format(said))
            

auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=SCOPEs)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

searchSong('The TWist')
```

If click on start_playback() in VS code.

The detail parameter will show with a description.

You need to provide `context_uri` or `uris` value for playing music.
The `uris` is array type of `track_id`, I set it.
[image]

Result

[image]